# How to generate loop kind of behaviour in SQL query to fetch multiple queries & compare results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am unable to generate a looping kind of behaviour in a SQL query.

I am having two tables:

**Table A**

```
Id Brand Prod_Id Alt_Prod_Id
1    A      2         5
2    B      3         9
3    C      5         9
```

**Table B**

```
Id Prod_Id   Rate
1    2         5
2    3         9
2    5         7
2    9         9
```

Rate in Table B needs to be looked up for each brands Prod_ID & Alt_Prod_Id & select the least value between 2 found value

The expected result / output is:

```
Brand Min_Prod_Val
  A         5
  B         9
  C         7
```

Can this be done in a query?

Thanks!

Comment: You neither need nor should you want loops.  SQL works best using set-logic, and this can be done with such a query.

Comment: You have four different DBMSs tagged here, which is the actual version of sql that you are using?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I have updated the tagging. Oracle is what I am using.

Answer (score 2):

You could join `tableb` twice (once for `prod_id`, another for `alt_prod_id`), and then select the smallest `rate`:

```
select 
    a.brand,
    least(b1.rate, b2.rate) min_prod_val
from tablea a
inner join tableb b1 on b1.prod_id = a.prod_id
inner join tableb b2 on b2.prod_id = a.alt_prod_id
```

It is unclear which database you are using. If that's SQL Server: it does not support `least()`, so you need a `case` expression:

```
case when b1.rate < b2.rate then b1.rate else b2.rate end min_prod_val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single join and `GROUP BY` the brand:

```sql
SELECT a.Brand,
       MIN( b.rate ) AS min_prod_val
FROM   TableA A
       INNER JOIN TableB b
       ON ( b.prod_id IN ( a.prod_id, a.alt_prod_id ) )
GROUP BY a.Brand
```

Or you can use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT a.Brand,
       (
         SELECT MIN( rate )
         FROM   TableB b
         WHERE  b.prod_id IN ( a.prod_id, a.alt_prod_id )  
       ) AS min_prod_val
FROM   TableA A
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=10128a86f882b71244be4d5c594f0955)